# EWS script to create new contact then add it to public folder> parent folder >folder containing contact items

Tags: exchangewebservices, contacts, public-folders

New to using EWS. I have a PowerShell script that automates onboarding new users via input (that all works great). I would like to add the following function to the script: Create new contact, then add it to the public folder > parent folder > folder containing contact items. So that all users can see the company contact

All the information for the contact card (see below) is predefined in the script already i just do not know how to use EWS.

```
Full Name
Company
Job Title
Email
Phone number (Business and Fax)
Address
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new contact by using the following link:

[Creating contacts by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ee693007(v%3Dexchg.80))

Also, if you want to add it to public folder, You can use the MoveItem operation in EWS or the Item.Move() method in the EWS Managed API to move email messages, contacts, and other mailbox items into and out of a public folder.

[Public folder access with EWS in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/public-folder-access-with-ews-in-exchange)